# Definition of sufficiently positive divisor on a variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth, projective, irreducible variety of dimension $n$. In some literature, there is a mention of sufficiently positive divisor on $X$. I am unable to find a precise definition for it.

Therefore, my question is that what is a precise definition of a sufficiently positive divisor on $X$ and for a given such $X$ if does such a divisor always exist?

I have one follow up question: Does such a divisor $D$ on $X$ always satisfy the property that for any vector bundle $E$ on $X$, $H^i(X, E(D))=0$ for $i >0$? (or should we take this as definition)?

Any  suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I would need to see an example of this usage to be sure, but I interpret "property $X$ holds for a sufficiently positive divisor $D$" as "property $X$ holds for a $D+nH$ for some large $n$", where $H$ is the hyperplane divisor.

As for your second question, there is no such divisor $D$ such that twisting any vector bundle $E$ by it kills all the higher cohomology, simply because there exist "sufficiently negative" line bundles. But for a specific bundle $E$ there always exists such a sufficiently positive divisor $D$, which depends on $E$.

Comment: suppose we have a fine moduli space of rank $r$, slope stable bundles with fixed Chern classes on a smooth projective irreducible variety $X$ with $U$ be the universal sheaf. Now if the moduli space has the property that for all bundles second cohomology onward all cohomologies vanish, then it is stated that for a sufficiently positive divisor, for any $p$ in the moduli space all the higher cohomologies (except the zeroth) vanish for the vector bundles $U$ restricted to $X$ times $p$ tensor $D$. Can we say that such a divisor $D$ will always exist?

Comment: I have absolutely no knowledge of moduli spaces, and no idea what is a restriction of a vector bundle to $X\times p \otimes D$.

Comment: $U$ is a vector bundle on $X$ times the moduli space. therefore for any $p$ from the moduli space you can restrict it to $X$ times $p$, this can be identified as a vector bundlle on $X$ itself and hence can be tensorized with $D$ (considered as a line bundle on $X$).. I am writing it in words as I dont have access to proper keyboard at the moment.

Comment: This is true, and there is nothing special about your situation here, it's just a result on quasiprojective varieties. I think this is called Serre's vanishing.

Comment: In the statement of Serre Vansishing, $D$ will depend upon the coherent sheaf. But here the statement made is that one can obtain sufficiently positive divisor $D$ such that for any $p$ in the moduli space, the cohomologies (from index $1$) of that tensorized bundles vanish.

Comment: Again, I am incompetent in moduli spaces, but this should be true. Since your Chern classes are fixed, the bundles in consideration can't be "too negative".